# Series convergence for a conditional probability mass function

Tags: calculus, probability, sequences-and-series, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

In the book of H. Taylor and S. Karlin, "*An Introduction to Stochastic Modeling*" it is given the following example:

Let $X$ have a binomial distribution with parameters $p$ and $N$, where $N$ has a binomial distribution with parameters $q$ and $M$. Given the conditional probability mass function:
\begin{equation}
p_{X|N}(k|n)=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}
\end{equation}
and the marginal distribution:
\begin{equation}
p_{N}(n)=\frac{M!}{n!(M-n)!}q^n(1-q)^{M-n}
\end{equation}
find the marginal distribution of $X$.

It then follows in the solution that the marginal distribution is derived by the law of total probability in its conditional probability expression:
\begin{align}
Pr\{X=k \}& =\sum_{n=0}^M p_{X|N}(k|n)p_{N}(n)\\
&=\sum_{n=k}^M \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\frac{M!}{n!(M-n)!}q^n(1-q)^{M-n} \\
& =\frac{M!}{k!}(1-q)^M\left( \frac{pq}{1-q}\right)^k \sum_{n=k}^M \frac{1}{(n-k)!(M-n)!}(1-p)^{n-k}\left( \frac{q}{1-q}\right)^{n-k}
\end{align}
It is claimed that this particular sum converges to the quantity:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=k}^M \frac{1}{(n-k)!(M-n)!}(1-p)^{n-k}\left( \frac{q}{1-q}\right)^{n-k}=\left[1+\frac{q(1-p)}{1-q} \right]^{M-k}
\end{equation}
which looks like a binomial series to me.

I would like to ask the following:

- How to interpret the fact that the sum of the total probability starts from $n=k$ instead of $n=0$ as written in the original formula?
- How can I prove that the series actually converges to that quantity?

Comment: Just quickly glancing it looks like the terms are 0 unless $n \ge k$, check the definition of the factorial for negative values, it is usually assumed to be 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Let $X$ have a binomial distribution with parameters $p$ and $N$, where $N$ has a binomial distribution with parameters $q$ and $M$. Given the conditional probability mass function:
> >     $$\begin{equation}
> > p_{X|N}(k|n)=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}
> > \end{equation}$$
> >     and the marginal distribution:
> >     $$\begin{equation}
> > p_{N}(n)=\frac{M!}{n!(M-n)!}q^n(1-q)^{M-n}
> > \end{equation}$$
> >     find the marginal distribution of $X$.
>
> - Why was interpret the fact that the sum of the total probability starts from $n=k$ instead of $n=0$ as written in the original formula?

That neglects to indicate the support for the binomial distributions.

$$\begin{equation}
p_{X|N}(k|n)=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\begin{cases} 1&:& n\in\Bbb N, k\in\Bbb N, 0\leq k\leq n\leq M\\0&:& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}
\end{equation}$$

$$\begin{equation}
p_{N}(n)=\frac{M!}{n!(M-n)!}q^n(1-q)^{M-n}\begin{cases} 1&:& n\in\Bbb N, 0\leq n\leq M\\0&:& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}
\end{equation}$$

It then follows that their product is zero when $n<k$, so:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{M} p_{X\mid N}(k\mid n)p_N(n) ~=~ 0+\sum_{n=k}^{M} p_{X\mid N}(k\mid n)p_N(n)$$

> It is claimed that this particular sum converges to the quantity:
>
> > $$\begin{equation}
> > \sum_{n=k}^M \frac{1}{(n-k)!(M-n)!}(1-p)^{n-k}\left( \frac{q}{1-q}\right)^{n-k}=\left[1+\frac{q(1-p)}{1-q} \right]^{M-k}
> > \end{equation}$$
>
> which looks like a binomial series to me.
>
> - How can I prove that the series actually converges to that quantity?

You can not, because it *does not* converge to that quantity.

It *looks* like a binomial series, so expand the suspected binomial series .

$$\left[1+\frac{q(1-p)}{1-q} \right]^{M-k} ~{= \sum_{j=0}^{M-k} \dfrac{(M-k)!}{j!~(M-k-j)!}\left(\frac{q(1-p)}{1-q}\right)^{j}\\= (M-k)!\sum_{n=k}^{M}\dfrac{1}{(n-k)!~(M-n)!} \left(\frac{q(1-p)}{1-q}\right)^{n-k}}$$

So on examining this result, clearly: $$\sum_{n=k}^{M}\dfrac{1}{(n-k)!~(M-n)!} \left(\frac{q(1-p)}{1-q}\right)^{n-k}~=~\frac {(1-qp)^{M-k}}{(M-k)!~(1-q)^{M-k}}$$

---

$$\therefore \quad p_X(k)~=~\dfrac{M!}{k!~(M-k)!}(pq)^k (1-pq)^{M-k}\begin{cases}1&:& k\in\Bbb N, 0\leq k\leq M\\0&:& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: I see. Therefore there was a mistake in the book. Thank you for clarifying it.

Comment: Excuse me for coming back to it, I also have the following question: Is the conditional probability mass function given because it is not possible to be derived or is it derived somehow? Is there a link you can direct me or should I start a new post about it? Many thanks.

Comment: I don't know about the original question, but this situation would arise if you had, say, two biased coins which show heads with rates $q$ and $p$.  You toss the first coin $M$ times, count the heads ($N$) and then throw the second coin that many times and count the heads ($X$).  Then $N\sim\mathcal{Bin}(M, q)$ and $X\mid N\sim\mathcal{Bin}(N, p)$ are identified; and we should likewise anticipate $X\sim\mathcal{Bin}(M, pq)$ .